# Find a matrix that doesn't have cube root

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, roots

The problem is:

> Is the statement true or false: Every 3x3 Matrices has the cube root.

After looking through all questions relevant to the problem in this forum, I realize that the statement is false (Or at least, people said that). However, all the proofs are unclear.

So I post the question here, again. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All you have to do to disprove the claim is to find one matrix that does _not_ have a cube root. $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ ought to work.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  i see. using simple matrix multiplication would work in proving this. however, i wonder there is another way clearer to prove this.

Comment: i mean proving that the matrix you mentioned does not have cube root

Comment: @ThinhNgo If $A$ is Henning's matrix, then $A^2=0$. If $B^3=A$, then $B^6=0$. However, if $C$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $C^m=0$, for some integer $m$, then also $C^n=0$.

Comment: x @Thinh: I don't know which prerequisites you have, but what I had in mind is that the only eigenvalue of my matrix is $0$, so if it has a cube root $B$, every eigenvalue of $B$ must be $0$ too. This restricts the possibilites for what the Jordan canonical form of $B$ can be to one of three possibilities, and in each of these cases we find by direct computation that $B^3=0$, so $B$ was not a cube root after all ...

Comment: @egreg thx. It's a good idea. I will give it a try.

Comment: @HenningMakholm but i think eigenvalue only exist in diagonalizable matrices, doesn't it?

Comment: @ThinhNgo: No, a matrix does not need to be diagonalizable in order to have eigenvalues. A real matrix does not need to have _real_ eigenvalues (ones with odd dimension have at least one, though), but a complex one always has -- so what I'm proving here is that there is no _complex_ cube root. and therefore not any real one either.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks. christian's solution helps me a lot, and now i understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix
$$A:=\left[\matrix{0&1&0\cr 0&0&0\cr 0&0&0\cr}\right]$$
is triangular, hence its eigenvalues are the diagonal elements $0$, $0$, $0$. If $\lambda\in{\mathbb C}$ is an eigenvalue of a potential third root $B$ of $A$ then $\lambda^3=0$, hence $B$ has eigenvalues $0$, $0$, $0$ as well. But such a $B$ has Jordan form
$${\rm jord}(B)=\left[\matrix{0&\epsilon_1&0\cr 0&0&\epsilon_2\cr 0&0&0\cr}\right]\ ,\qquad\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\in\{0,1\} ,$$
which would imply $B^3=0$, hence $B^3\ne A$. It follows that $A$ has no third root.

Comment: it's such a clear solution i'm looking for. Thanks very much.